# Is there a way for my discord.py embed field name and value be aligned

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is there a way for my discord embeds name and value to be on the same line? I went through the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed) and found nothing. Any answer would help, thank you!

Comment: Do you mean something like `Name - Value`? If so, then I don't think embeds support this. You'll probably have to cheat and do some formatting in the description instead of using fields.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, At most there can be 3 Fields in one line using `inline=True`, its discord's API rule

You can not make more fields in one line.

Comment: that didn't really answer my question

Comment: so what you want, text alignment?

Answer (score 0):

You should add everything in the 'name' value, then add an invisible character in the 'value' value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).